# Calculate fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the fundamental group of the complement of a certain graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16080/finding-the-fundamental-group-of-the-complement-of-a-certain-graph)

The problem is in the picture.[image]

[image]

My question is: how to show $\pi_1(Y)$ has the presentation $\langle a,b,c \mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cb^{\varepsilon}c^{-1} \rangle$ for $\varepsilon = \pm 1$, and how to prove $\pi_1(Y) = \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-Z)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can give a description of this manifold as a CW-complex with: one $0$ cell; three $1$ cells named "a," "b," and "c"; and one $2$-cell, attached along the given relation.

Comment: @you Hi,now I can give Y the CW-complex structure,but how to prove $\pi_1(Y)=\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-Z)$?I can image it,but cann't prove it.